# Usage of executor in android architecture components

Tags: android, multithreading, android-room, android-architecture-components

```
public class UserRepository {
private final Webservice webservice;
private final UserDao userDao;
private final Executor executor;

@Inject
public UserRepository(Webservice webservice, UserDao userDao, Executor executor) {
    this.webservice = webservice;
    this.userDao = userDao;
    this.executor = executor;
}

public LiveData<User> getUser(String userId) {
    refreshUser(userId);
    // Returns a LiveData object directly from the database.
    return userDao.load(userId);
}

private void refreshUser(final String userId) {
    // Runs in a background thread.
    executor.execute(() -> {
        // Check if user data was fetched recently.
        boolean userExists = userDao.hasUser(FRESH_TIMEOUT);
        if (!userExists) {
            // Refreshes the data.
            Response<User> response = webservice.getUser(userId).execute();

            // Check for errors here.

            // Updates the database. The LiveData object automatically
            // refreshes, so we don't need to do anything else here.
            userDao.save(response.body());
        }
    });
}
}
```

The code above is part of ["Guide to app architecture"](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide), from Android Documentation, using architecture components. Inside *refreshUser* method they fetch data from network using retrofit if data doesn't exists in cache.

My question is: Why do they use an executor for this? Retrofit itself is already capable of running network request asynchronously.

Please clarify what exactly is an Executor and its need in this example for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of the box room doesn't support database access on the main thread so the executor is there to ensure the work is done on a separate thread.

By using the executor they've also opted to use the synchronous retrofit call which will block the executing thread.

In the code you're referencing the executor is a SingleThreadExecutor, this essentially creates a single worker thread to execute its work, which in this case will execute the Room DB operations along with handling the synchronous retrofit call.

This is the link the to executor in the above example.
https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/GithubArchitectureComponents/blob/98e0a048791f18646c730323c242c670c3eaf453/app/src/main/java/com/boisneyphilippe/githubarchitecturecomponents/di/module/AppModule.java#L48

Along with the official docs for newSingleThreadExecutor:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()

Comment: Hello Chris can you please check my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173972/when-and-why-would-one-use-a-group-of-executor

Comment: Technically, Room *does* support database access on the main thread by calling allowMainThreadQueries() when creating the database. However, good practice is to only access the database on a background thread.

Answer (score 7):

> What exactly is an Executor?

An Executor is normally used instead of explicitly creating threads. For example, rather than invoking `new Thread(new RunnableTask()).start()` for each of a set of tasks, you might use:

```
Executor executor = someExecutor();  // any class implementing `Executor` interface
executor.execute(new Runnable1());
executor.execute(new Runnable2());
```

> Why do they use an executor for this? Retrofit itself is already
> capable of running network request asynchronously.

They have used it to switch to a background worker thread from the main thread, to perform a database operation, since by default, **Room** architecture component does not allow queries on the `MainThread`.

**Retrofit** is capable of performing async network requests, but they are doing a synchronous network request here instead after which they are just performing a insert operation on local database using Room component.

For more information about Executor framework, you can follow this guide: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor

Comment: What is the someExecutor() means here?

Comment: @blackjack it's too late, but `someExecutor` is a class that implements `Executor` interface.