# What is the real use of Executor in android Paging Library?

Tags: android, paging, threadpoolexecutor

I have seen most examples using  Executor in the DataSource Classes which is usually passed to DataSourceFactory from ViewModel and then to DataSource classes.How do I make use of executor. What Benefits/advantage of using Executor.

VIEWMODEL

```
public FooViewModel{

public FooViewModel() {

    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    //pasing executor here.
    FooDataSourceFactory itemDataSourceFactory = new 
   FooDataSourceFactory(executor);


}
```

DATASORUCEFACTORY

```
public class FooDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {
private FooDataSource itemDataSource;
private Executor executor;
//creating the mutable live data
private MutableLiveData<FooDataSource> itemLiveDataSource = new 
MutableLiveData<>();

public FooDataSourceFactory(Executor executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
}


@Override
public DataSource create() {
    //passing executor here..
    itemDataSource = new FooDataSource(executor);

    //posting the dataSource to get the values
    itemLiveDataSource.postValue(itemDataSource);

    //returning the dataSource
    return itemDataSource;

.................
}
```

DATASOURCE

```
public class FooDataSource { 

 FooDataSource(Executor executor){
       //don't know what to do with executor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor)
>
> An object that executes submitted Runnable tasks. This interface provides a way of decoupling task submission from the mechanics of how each task will be run, including details of thread use, scheduling, etc. An Executor is normally used instead of explicitly creating threads. For example, rather than invoking
> `new Thread(new RunnableTask()).start()` for each of a set of tasks, you might use:
> `executor.execute(runnable);`

In paging library, the goal is to do everything asynchronously.
The Executor can help you with that, insert and retrieve data async easily, without explicitly using threads at all.

If you are developing an app with MVVM architecture, it's possible that you have some 'repository' class that handles the data locally and/or api calls. In that case, it is recommended to query your db with executors.

You can also use an executor for observing a paged list, in case you want to do something not on the main thread when the data changes.

---

In your specific case, you may not need an executor inside your `DataSource` and `DataSourceFactory`.
it depends on what you are doing in those classes. 
If you're fetching data from the internet, there are many libraries like [volley][2] and [retrofit2][3] that doing the http calls asynchronously, so no need for an executor.

When retrieving the data from a local DB like [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html):

> Out of the box room doesn't support database access on the main thread so the executor is there to ensure the work is done on a separate thread. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52165278/10470378)

I hope you find my answer helpful.

Comment: Thank You for your time and effort. It helped me a lot.